# URL rewrite rule to rewrite potential extension

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

The following rule rewrites `domain.com/2009/05/url-of-some-awesomeness/` to `domain.com/url-of-some-awesomeness/`:

```
    RewriteRule ^([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{1,2})/(.+)$ /$3 [NC,R=301,L]
```

There are some old links coming into the site that retain an older structure the had .html so the rule needs to be modified to rewrite the above or `domain.com/2009/05/url-of-some-awesomeness.html` or `domain.com/2009/05/url-of-some-awesomeness/feed/` to `domain.com/url-of-some-awesomeness/`

Comment: So if original URI is `domain.com/2009/05/foo.html` do you want it to redirect to `domain.com/foo.html`

Comment: If you are simply stripping any "/yyyy/mm" value, you'd want to add a canonical meta tag so seo page rank is assigned to the primary page. Further reading: http://www.seomoz.org/blog/canonical-url-tag-the-most-important-advancement-in-seo-practices-since-sitemaps

Comment: @anubhava That is somewhat what the original rewrite accomplishes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose the .htm or .html is at the end and you don't want it to be part of `$3`?

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{1,2})/((?:(?!\.html?$).)+)(?:\.html?)?$ /$3 [NC,R=301,L]
```

Hint: Next time try to be absolutely specific. A *"there are a few cases in which the original request may have a .html .htm or /feed/"* is about as vague as it can get.

Comment: Correct. I updated the question so other viewers will more clearly understand the question.